# robot framework selenium How to retrieve a key from a diccionary

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Recently I am attempting doing automation test in python with selenium-robot framework in two different browsers, but I am having an error when i try log the Alias of a Browser. The error says: "Dictionary '@{alias}' has no key '1'".

The code is this on:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}  http://google.com
${browser}  chrome

*** Test Cases ***
TC to demostrate Browser Operation Keywords in Robot Framework
    [Documentation]  TC to demostrate Browser Operation Keywords in Robot Framework

    Open Browser  http://google.com  Chrome  alias=ChromeRCV

    Maximize Browser Window

    Open Browser  about:blank  ff  alias=RCVFF

    &{alias}  Get Browser Aliases

    Log  @{alias}[1]

    @{browser_ID}  Get Browser Ids

    Log  @{browser_ID}[1]

    Switch Browser  1

    Input Text  //*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input  RCVAcademy

    Sleep  4s

    Switch Browser  @{alias}[1]

    Go To  http://salesforce.com

    Close All Browsers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how Robot interprets the variables. Since you have written `@{alias}[1]` Robot assumes that the value on index 1 of list `alias` is also a list. To avoid this issue in future, think first what you want to *get out* from the variable before assigning the `$`, `@` or `&`. You can see better explanation in the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable-syntax).

Consider the below example

```
&{DICT}=    {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

# Get a list of keys
@{KEYS}=    @{DICT.keys}
# ==> @{KEYS}= ["key1", "key2]

# Get a value from dictionary
${VALUE}=    ${DICT}[key1]
# ==> ${VALUE}= value1

# Get a value from list
${VALUE}=    ${LIST}[0]
# ==> ${VALUE}= key1
```

As you can see, only when returning a list value, are we using the `@` sign. This is because whenever using the `@` sign, Robot will interpret the given value as a list of multiple values and attempt to pass each value separately - This is also why normally lists are passed with `$` as arguments to make Robot pass them as single variable instead of multiple separate values.

Additionally you are attempting to return a value from a *dictionary* with a list-like index. This will not work that way - You'll either have to access the value based on the key or then as a list of keys **or** values.

Since you only need the key to access the browser with the alias, you might as well simply use the following

```
Log    ${aliases.keys()}[1]

# or to log everything in the dictionary

Log    ${aliases}
```

Comment: "you have written @{alias}[1] Robot assumes that the value on index 1 of list alias is also a list." that's simply not true. Using @ in front of a dict variable will actually ask RF to return the dict's keys, and then you'll target a specific one - the integer 1 in this case.

Comment: That method does not work at least on the newest RF (4.1) running on Python 3.9.7 - I double-checked and still that returns only with the error ``Dictionary '@{alias}' has no key '1'`` after creating dictionary with 2 key value pairs and attempting to log from index 1. @Todor Minakov

Comment: dictionaries don't have indices, that's a property lists have; dictionary have key-value pairs. If you create a dict item which key is 1, then you'll be able to retrieve it.

Comment: Exactly, that's why its still true that using ``@{dictionary}[key]`` will attempt to return a _list_ value from that mentioned _key_ - Having a non-list value on the key will return error ``Value of variable -- is not list or list-like``. Using the ``@{dictionary}`` does return all the keys, but since the variable is still a dictionary, if you wish to access any value behind it that value must be list-like when using ``@``. Anyway, the question seemed to be about accessing a dictonary key like a list and that's what I answered to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have misunderstood [the return value of the `Get Browser Aliases`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Browser%20Aliases) - it returns a dict where the key is the alias you have given to an instance, and the value is the index.

Thus when you have typed `[1]` you are targeting the alias 1 (integer), but that's not one of the aliases you've set - and thus it's not a key in that dictionary, and thus - the error you got.

Change to this - the "ChromeRCV" is an alias you actually have, and it should work:

```
Log  @{alias}['ChromeRCV']
```